# Trying to Make a Sidebar/Tab on Specific Posts

Tags: plugins, sidebar, design, tabs

I have searched and contacted some plugin providers but couldn't find what I am looking for. In summary, I am trying to make a Sidebar that details the hotel and course info next to a post. Something similar to [this](https://golftourismengland.com/golf-clubs/st-georges-hill/) where the sidebar exists in the left. Anything you guys can recommend?

Comment: The site you reference is a WordPress site; have you reached out to them to ask about how they're doing it?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic on this stack's scope, but if you'd like to do it yourself it would require some knowledge of theme file editing and HTML/CSS/PHP. Either that or some themes have this functionality built in if you find the right one.